# HMM with multinomial observation distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm writing a simple HMM with multinomial observations in TensorFlow-probability, but I couldn't get the most probable sequence of hidden states correctly. `posterior_mode` always returns the first state (state 0), regardless of the model.

The code below illustrates what I mean with a trivial case:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tf.enable_eager_execution()
tfd = tfp.distributions

prior = tfd.Categorical(probs=[0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
transition = tfd.Categorical(probs=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],\
                                    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],\
                                    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
emission = tfd.Multinomial(total_count=[1,1,1],\
                            probs=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],\
                                   [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],\
                                   [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

trueModel = tfd.HiddenMarkovModel(initial_distribution=prior,
                                  transition_distribution=transition,
                                  observation_distribution=emission,
                                  num_steps=4)

sample=trueModel.sample().numpy()

print("SAMPLE:\n", sample)

print("\nMOST PROBABLE STATES:\n", trueModel.posterior_mode(sample).numpy())
```

But this code returns:

```
SAMPLE:
 [[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]

MOST PROBABLE STATES:
 [0 0 0 0]
```

which for this trivial example is impossible, given the prior, transitions and observation distributions. Other values for the distributions return the same output for the most probable hidden states.

Am I missing something here or is there an issue with TF-probability?